# Equivalent formulation of linear logic with more axioms and less inference rules

Tags: lo.logic, linear-logic

We can formulate classical (sequent) logic with only the structural inference rules including cut, and a collection of axioms like $A, B \vdash A \wedge B$. This is equivalent to the usual sequent calculus of classical logic, in the sense that the provable sequents are the same.

Can we do the same with classical linear logic? Assuming only **Ax**: $\frac{}{A \vdash A}$ and **Cut**: $\frac{\Gamma \vdash A, \Delta\quad\Xi,A \vdash \Phi}{\Gamma, \Xi \vdash \Delta, \Phi}$, and a collection of sequents as axioms, can we recover the full MALL? Of the four binary connectives, we can easily come up with the elimination axiom for $\&$ and $⅋$ (`\lpar` is not supported by MO), and the introduction axiom for $\otimes$ and $\oplus$. However, I'm having difficulty with the other side. It seems that if we allow ourselves additionally the rules for $\multimap$, then I *think* the elimination axiom for $\otimes$ would be $A \multimap (B \multimap C) \vdash (A \otimes B) \multimap C$. But I'm not able to proceed any further.

Also, I haven't considered negation yet. Perhaps it will be better to regard negation as an involution on the formulae, which might give us a way to relate the different connectives.

Is there any previous work on this? Or can it be proven that such a formulation is impossible? (This might be achieved by demonstrating that sequents as opposed to rules never impose enough constraints on the logic.)

Comment: You should have a look at *Residuated Lattices: An Algebraic Glimpse at Substructural  Logics* by Galatos, Jipsen, Kowalski, and Ono. Among other things, they give various presentations of substructural logics (of which MALL is a special case). E.g., IIRC there is a Hilbert calculus for FLe (of which MALL is an axiomatic extension) whose only proper rules of inference are modus ponens $A,A\to B/B$ and adjunction $A,B/A\land B$. (I suppose $\to$ is denoted by the lollipop thingy in linear logic; $\land$ is additive conjunction, I can’t remember how it is written in LL.) You can translate ...

Comment: ... that into a sequent calculus with only a few inference rules.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Aww that book is probably what I've been vaguely wanting to read. It should really be an answer.